# Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Estou tentando fazer um código em Haskell que elimine todos os valores repetidos de uma lista, o código está assim:

```
import Data.List

filtraLista [] = []
filtraLista (xs : []) =  [xs]
sort filtraLista (x:y:xs)
  |x == y = filtraLista (y : xs)
  |otherwise = x : filtraLista (y : xs)
```

O código compila mas não funciona, aparece sempre o erro:

> *** Exception: main.hs:(3,1)-(4,29): Non-exhaustive patterns in function filtraLista

Não consigo identificar qual o erro

Answer (score 3):

Está função faz me lembrar a nub que já está definida em Haskell fazer apenas isto não resolveria o problema?

```
import Data.List

filtraLista [] = []
filtraLista [x] = [x]
filtraLista (x:xs) = x : filter (/= x) (filtraLista xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Este erro acontece quando não é possível casar a entrada da função com nenhum dos padrões definidos para a função, e isso aconteceu porque há um erro na quarta linha do seu programa.

Na quarta linha você escrever

```
sort filtraLista (x:y:xs)
```

que siginifica que você está definindo uma função chamada  `sort` de dois argumentos, os quais foram chamados de `filtraLista` e `(x:y:xs)`, sendo que, o correto seria você escrever algo como

```
filtraLista sort (x:y:xs)
```

porque, aí sim, você estaria continuando a definição de `filtraLista`. Porém, se você escrever isso, um erro diferente acontecerá:

> Equations for `filtraLista' have different numbers of arguments

que acontece porque os dois primeiros padrões resultam numa função de um argumento de entrada, enquanto que o último resulta numa de dois argumentos de entrada.

Para que você possa definir a função corretamente, tenho uma sugestão:

1. Escreva `filtraLista` supondo que as listas de entrada estarão
   sempre ordenadas. Dessa forma, você não precisa usar `sort`.
2. Renomeei `filtraLista` para `filtraHelper`. E depois defina `filtraLista` como sendo `filtraHelper` recebendo o argumento de `filtraLista` já ordenados, ou seja: `filtraLista xs = filtraHelper (sort xs)`.
3. User `where` para embutir a definição de `filtraHelper` dentro de `filtraLista` para que o usuário final não tenha acesso a ela:

```
filtraLista xs = filtraHelper (sort xs)
  where filtraHelper ...
```

Essa prática se chama *worker wrapper* e é bastante comum em Haskell. Você pode ler mais sobre isso [aqui (em inglês)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Worker_wrapper).

Por fim, uma pergunta que talvez você tenha é:

> Se há uma `sort` que foi importada de `Data.List`, como foi possível definir uma nova `sort`? Não deveria ter causado erro de compilação? O que aconteceu com a de `Data.List`?

É possível, sim, sobrescrever funções importadas. Contundo, elas sempre estarão disponíveis por meio de seu nome completo (o termo usual é "nome qualificado", ou ainda "nome completamente qualificado"). Ou seja, mesmo que você crie uma nova `sort`, para que a versão importada seja acessada você deve escrever `Data.List.sort`. Para entender melhor como funciona importação de módulos recomendo o capítulo "Módulos" de LYHFGG ([leia aqui em português](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/modules#loading-modules)).

Answer (score 1):

Você definiu `filtraLista` para lista vazia e também com um elemento, mas ficou faltando para dois ou mais elementos, daí o `Non-exhaustive patterns`. Na linha 5, você começou dizendo que o nome da função era `sort` ao invés de filtraLista.

Refatorei um pouco a função e ficou assim:

```hs
import Data.List

filtraLista [] = []
filtraLista (x : []) =  [x]
filtraLista lista =
  let
    (x:y:xs) = sort lista
  in
    if x == y
      then filtraLista (y : xs)
      else x : filtraLista (y : xs)
```